# How to register yaml routes as PHP?

Tags: php, symfony

First I added a new routing_dev file as php

```
framework:
    router:
#        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.php"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
```

Now I'm registering the routes according to the 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

However I'm having an issue, when I register a yaml route example:

```
gabriel_auth:
    resource: "@GabrielAuthBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

gabriel_messaging:
    resource: "@GabrielMessagingBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

like this on the file

```
$collection->addCollection(
    $loader->import("@GabrielAuthBundle/Controller/", "annotation")
);

$collection->addCollection(
    $loader->import("@GabrielMessagingBundle/Controller/", "annotation")
);
```

then it does work, however 
I can't find a way to add these type of resources to the collection:

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler
```

this is my best try

```
$collection->addCollection(
    $loader->import(
        '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml')->addPrefix('/_profiler')
);

$collection->addCollection(
    $loader->import(
   '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml')->addPrefix('/_wdt')
);
```

it throws this error

> FileLoaderLoadException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection::addCollection() must be an
>   instance of Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection, null given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the doc http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouteCollection.html#method_addPrefix

```
public addPrefix(string $prefix, array $defaults = array(), array    $requirements = array())

 Adds a prefix to the path of all child routes.

Parameters
string  $prefix     An optional prefix to add before each pattern of the route collection
array   $defaults   An array of default values
array   $requirements   An array of requirements
```

This function has **no return**

Thats's why you got `null`

Try:

```
$profilerCollection = $loader->import(  '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml');
$profilerCollection->addPrefix('/_profiler');
$collection->addCollection( $profilerCollection);
```